# Definition of Parabola

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question

Every point on the parabola $y=\sqrt{2x-1}$ is equidistant from the $y$-axis and which of the following points?

(A) $(\frac{1}{2},0)$

(B) $(1,0)$

(C) $(\frac{3}{2},0)$

(D) $(2,0)$

(E) $(\frac{5}{2},0)$

I found the domain of the function to be $x$ is greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{2} (x\geq \frac{1}{2})$. Hence I guessed the shortest distance from the $y$-axis would be $(\frac{1}{2},0)$. However, the answer in the textbook is $(1,0)$. I don't really understand how they arrived at that.

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

It's not about the shortest distance at all. It's about the geometrical definition of a parabola. You need to read the definition of the *directrix* and the *focus* of a parabola and how to find them from an equation of a parabola. The question essentially tells you that the $y$-axis is the directrix of this parabola and asks you to find its focus.

Hint: the equation of this parabola (or rather, half of a parabola, because of the square root) can be rewritten as $y^2=2x-1$ (along with the condition that $y\ge0$). You know where the vertex is, you're given the directrix, and now find the focus.

Comment: Now I see. I don't know what I was thinking about earlier. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A parabola is the locus of points equidistant from a fixed point (the focus) and a fixed line not passing through this point (the directrix).  You are basically given the directrix, which never intersects the parabola, is the $y$ axis.  So you need to find the focus.

The parabola is clearly symmetric about the $x$ axis passing through $(1/2,0)$ on this axis, which is the vertex.  Then the line segment from this vertex to the focus and the segment perpendicular to the directrix merge into a single longer line segment where the vertex is the midpoint from the directrix to the focus.  You see that this segment meets the directrix at $(0,0)$ and the vertex/midpoint is $(1/2,0)$ so the focus must be $(1,0)$ = choice B.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see where I mixed things up